# Plural cref to theorem-like environment, singular cref to enumerate item inside it

Tags: cross-referencing, theorems, cleveref

I have a theorem-like environment, `examples` that always will include an enumerate within its body. Using `cleveref`, how can I refer to the entire environment (i.e., all the enumerated items) with plural name 'Examples' yet refer to an individual item within it with the singular name 'Example'?  (And a range of items within it again using the plural name 'Examples'?)

**Example source:**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=red]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink,noabbrev,capitalize]{cleveref}

\swapnumbers

\declaretheoremstyle[
  headfont= \sffamily\bfseries,
  headpunct={\sffamily\bfseries.},
  postheadspace=0.5em,
  notefont=\sffamily\bfseries,
  headformat=\NAME\NUMBER\let\thmt@space\@empty\NOTE,
  bodyfont=\mdseries\itshape,
  spaceabove=12pt,spacebelow=12pt
]{thmstyle}

\theoremstyle{thmstyle}% default
\declaretheorem[name=Theorem,numberwithin=chapter]{theorem}

\declaretheoremstyle[
  headfont= \sffamily\bfseries,
  headpunct={\sffamily\bfseries.},
  postheadspace=0.5em,
  notefont=\sffamily\bfseries,
 bodyfont=\normalfont,
 spaceabove=12pt,spacebelow=12pt
]{defstyle}

\theoremstyle{defstyle}
\newtheorem{examples}[theorem]{Examples}

\newlist{parensenum}{enumerate}{3}
\setlist[parensenum,1]{%
  label= \upshape(\arabic*),
  ref={\arabic*}, % strips formatting!
}

\crefname{examples}{Examples}{Examples}
\Crefname{examples}{Examples}{Examples}
\crefname{parensenumi}{}{}
\crefformat{parensenumi}{(#2#1#3)}
\Crefformat{parensenumi}{(#2#1#3)}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter}

\section{Section}

\large % for visibility in posting 
\begin{examples}\label{exs:several-exs}

\begin{parensenum}
\item\label{ex:one}      First example.
\item\label{ex:two}      Second example.
\item\label{ex:three}   Third example.

\end{parensenum}

\end{examples}

\textbf{References}

\begin{itemize}

\item  \cref{exs:several-exs}.  [OK as is.]

\item \cref{exs:several-exs} \cref{ex:two}. [Want singular ``Example'' in hyperlink.]

\item \crefrange{ex:two}{ex:three}.  [Want hyperlink: Examples 1.1 (2)--(3).]

[Can do this too verbosely as: \cref{exs:several-exs} \cref{ex:two}--\cref{ex:three}.]

\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

**Output**
[image: Defective singular/plural crefs]

**Question(s)**

My primary question is how to torture `cref`, or otherwise, so as to get the reference to a single item in the enumerated list within the `examples` environment to use singular "Example" instead of "Examples", while still keeping the plural "Examples" in the reference to the entire `examples` environment.

(If I must use the verbose form indicated to obtain a reference to a range of items in the enumerated list, that's OK — although I would prefer not to have to do that.)

If it makes a solution possible, or even significantly easier, I'm willing to give up the `nameinlinks` option to `cleveref`.

Comment: I would really like to encourage you to come up with a better way to distinguish verbally between instances of "Examples" as theorem-like environments and "Example"/"Examples" as enumerated items with `examples` environments. Otherwise, there will be a non-negligible risk that both you and your readers will be hopelessly confused as to what a given instance of the string "Examples" may refer to.

Comment: @Mico: Are you recommending that I make the distinction in my question, or in the document itself?

Comment: Both, I suppose. Your readers are almost certainly going to choke if they come across an expression such as "As illustrated by Examples (1) and (2) in Examples 3.4 ..." . Do you really expect them to keep track of the two different meanings of the plural word "Examples"?

Comment: In addition 'Examples 1.1' sounds ungrammatical to me. To make it grammatical, you'd have to say something like 'Set of examples 1.1' so that the singular 'Set' makes the reference sound OK. Compare 'Subsections 1` where you mean the three subsections in section 1. You need 'Section 1' or 'Subsections 1,1, 1,2 and 1,3' or 'the subsections in Section 1' or something similar. You can't use 'Subsections 1' to mean that and have it sound OK. (And it doesn't mean that, of course, so it isn't just how it sounds.)

Comment: @cfr: The ungrammatical sound is exactly why I asked the question!. Of course in my situation, where the enumerated items within the `examples` environment take the form (1), (2), etc., "Examples 1.8 (3)" doesn't sound quite as bad as, say, "Examples 1.8.3".

Comment: @murray But you *want* 'Examples 1.8', say, which sounds equally ungrammatical. That is, 'Examples 1.1' is not OK as it is, as far as the grammar is concerned. And if you didn't want the plural there, you wouldn't have the problem of distinguishing the cases.

Comment: @cfr: No, "Examples 1.8" is syntactically OK to my ear and eye when it refers to a set of examples. Since there is a whole list of examples under number 1.8, namely 1.8 (1), 1.8 (2), etc., it would certainly be incorrect to say "Example 1.8" and "set of examples 1.8" is not only too verbose but is not the title of the theorem-like item, which is "Examples". (Much as one can have a theorem-like item, say, "Axioms" that consists of a list of individual axioms.)

Comment: Still sounds wrong to me. '1.8 Examples', sure, but not 'Examples 1.8'. A set is singular. Just because something has parts, doesn't make the thing itself plural. The collection is singular. 'A network of nodes' but the network is singular. '1.8' contains examples, but it is not itself an instance of 'examples'.

Comment: @cfr: Silly for us to debate this point of grammar further. But if it were "1.8 Examples", do you have a viable solution that would produce `cleveref` link "1.8 Examples" to the whole `examples` environment but singular link "1.8 Example (3)" to just one of them, and plural link "1.8 Examples (3)-(5)" to the indicated range of them?

Comment: @murray Well, as I say, I wouldn't.